# Can't get geolocation in my ubuntu-16.04 browsers like Chrome and firefox

Tags: 14.04

I am building any angularjs app. I am trying to get geolocation of app/site visitors.

When a user visits my site, the there is a browser request to get user location. The request shows up well and after it's accepted, nothing is returned in my ubuntu browsers both firefox and chrome.

But when i check the app in my windows or android phone, user location is returned.

Is this ubuntu browser issue?

Here is the plunker to the geolocation test https://plnkr.co/edit/ezXP93oD9uEsn5r1pfO1?p=preview

```
 appProduct.service('geolocation', function ($q, $http) {
    var getLocation = function() {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            // If supported and have permission for location...
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                // 
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                    var result = {latitude : position.coords.latitude , longitude : position.coords.longitude}
                    // Adding randomization since we are all in the same location...
                    result.latitude += (Math.random() >0.5? -Math.random()/100 : Math.random()/100  );
                    result.longitude += (Math.random() >0.5? -Math.random()/100 : Math.random()/100  );
                    getNearbyCity(result.latitude, result.longitude).then(function(data){
                        result.address = data.data.results[1].formatted_address;
                        defer.resolve(result);
                    });
                }, function(error){
                    defer.reject({message: error.message, code:error.code});
                });
            }
            else {
                defer.reject({error: 'Geolocation not supported'});
            }
            return defer.promise;
        }
        var getNearbyCity = function (latitude, longitude){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude +',' + longitude +'&sensor=true';
            $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                     defer.resolve({data : data});
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  defer.reject({error: 'City not found'});
                });
            return defer.promise;
        }
        var service = {
            getLocation : getLocation,
            getNearbyCity: getNearbyCity
        };
        return service;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem is from the chromium or firefox from the ubuntu software center.

I removed chromium and downloaded chrome directly from the chrome website.
It will ask for compatibility. After which I click on the downloaded file , it takes you to ubuntu software center where it will tell you , that you are installing from a "third party".

After installed, my geolocation works fine. I guess the same thing will happen with firefox if you download the latest version and install it manually. Here is a link on how to install firefox manually...
https://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/download-and-install-firefox-manually-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/